# How do I redirect to a new page after a download using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form to download some files. The user selects the file from a drop down, and then presses a button to execute the download. The code looks like this:

```
  function downloadApp()
    {
    var dd = document.getElementById("OSselectDropdown");
    var OSchoice = dd.options[dd.selectedIndex].value;
    if (OSchoice == "win")
    {
        window.location.href = "https://" + top.location.host + "/download/win_install.exe";
    }
    if (OSchoice == "mac")
    {
        window.location.href = "https://" + top.location.host + "/download/mac_install.pkg";
    }
    if (OSchoice == "linux")
    {
        window.location.href = "https://" + top.location.host + "/download/linux_install.tar.gz";
    }
```

What I want to acheive is for the user to be taken to a new page once the download has started. However, I can't see how to do that because the download itself is essentially already a redirection to the downloadable file location using `window.location.href`. Once that is processed, it seems impossible to get the Javascript to then execute a second `window.location.href`.

Ideally, the download would start, and then the user would automatically end up on a new page I specify, while the download continues as a background process.

Even more ideally, on the new page I want to include a message saying "Thank you for downloading". That message should only appear on that page when the user has been brought there after having been through the download process.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

*(I do see there are many entries on this site for redirections and downloads, but, this seems to be the kind of issue where details matter, and none of them matched my situation closely enough as far as I could tell.)*

Answer (score 0):

first either redirect the user to thank you page using -

```
window.location = thankYouPageURL;
```

you can keep a different URL for every OS or you can pass parameters in get and process the GET parameters on JavaScript side using some library.

Or navigate on the same page to another part using hash.

```
location.hash = "#" + thankYouHash;
```

you can also make a div overlay or similar approach for this. after choosing the download options toggle the visibility of thankYouDiv and hide the previous div where the download options were present.

on the thankyou page/div/hash start the download using a new window or iframe.

**IFRAME -**

```
function startDownload(downloadUrl) {
  var downloadFrame = document.createElement("iframe"); 
  downloadFrame.setAttribute('src',downloadUrl);
  downloadFrame.setAttribute('style',"border: 0; clip: rect(0 0 0 0); height: 1px; margin: -1px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0; position: absolute; width: 1px;"); 
  document.body.appendChild(downloadFrame);  
}
```

**Download Window -**

```
function startDownload(downloadUrl) {
  window.open(downloadUrl, 'download_window', 'toolbar=0,location=no,directories=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizeable=0,width=1,height=1,top=0,left=0');
  window.focus();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

try to `location.href` instead of `window.location.href`

Comment: Thank you for responding. However, as I mentioned on the other answer, whether I use `window.location`, `location.href`, or `window.location.href`, if I have two of them, only the second of the two gets used.